# x-data value resets after clicking wire:click.prevent action

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

In a Blade component I have:

```
@if(Request::segment(1) === 'admin')
    <div x-data="{ admin: true }">
@else
    <div x-data="{ admin: false }">
@endif

    <div x-show="admin">
    ...
    </div>

</div>
```

So, when I visit `example.com/admin`, the admin `<div>` is visible.

Outside this component I have another component:

```
<a wire:click.prevent="create()" href="#">
    Add
</a>
```

With `create()` opening a modal on the page.

The problem is.. Once I click the link, `admin` is set to `false` in my first component. This while the url didn't change.

How can I keep `admin` set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding `wire:ignore` to a parent div

https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s4-wire-ignore